# Put logo with link on Clappr player

Tags: clappr

Hello and happy holidays,

Is it possible to add a logo to the clappr player and insert a link on it to an external site?

Thanks.

best regards

I found a way to insert the logo, but I don't know how to insert a link.

for the logo I used this code:

```
watermark: "https://clipart-library.com/images/qiB5pzki5.png", position: 'top-right',
```